# how to develop android scrollview with custom design

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm doing an android development of a commercial
app, I need to develop a scroll view as follow, need help, it must be continuous 
[image: scroll view]

Answer (score 0):

To develop this you have to use ViewPager carousel.

Comment: can you give me an example, if can it may really really help me a lot

Comment: Check this https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel. I hope it will help you.